# I'm getting missing operand somewhere within the picture provided

Tags: batch-file, windows-10, command-prompt

Trying to use a script to format and partition a 500 GB hdd for my Xbox one. Keeps getting missing operand when I select disk to use batch file on. I believe the error is here somewhere. Here is the whole code, I can not determine where the user error may be located.

```
echo.
set XBO_MESSAGE=* Disk %XBO_FORMAT_DRIVE% will be formatted as an Xbox One . . .                      *
echo %XBO_MESSAGE%
echo %XBO_MESSAGE% >> %XBO_LOG% 2>&1
:rpart


:: Start of diskpart remove existing partitions (works but clunky since partitions have to be removed individually)
:: Replaced with gdisk (remove existing partitions)
::echo select disk %XBO_FORMAT_DRIVE% > %XBO_DP_SCRIPT%
::echo list partition >> %XBO_DP_SCRIPT%
:: Determine the number of partitions to delete
::for /f "tokens=2" %%A in ('%XBO_DISKPART% /s %XBO_DP_SCRIPT% ^| findstr /b /r /c:" *Partition [^#]" ^| sort /r') do (
:: When the first partition is removed all other partitions cascade down
::echo select partition %%A >> !XBO_DP_SCRIPT!
::echo delete partition override >> !XBO_DP_SCRIPT!
::)

::echo p > %XBO_GD_SCRIPT%
::for /f "tokens=*" %%A in ('%XBO_GDISK% \\.\physicaldrive%XBO_FORMAT_DRIVE% ^< %XBO_GD_SCRIPT% ^| find /c "GPT: present"') do (set XBO_IS_GPT=%%A)
:: If already a GPT disk skip "convert gpt"
::if %XBO_IS_GPT% EQU 1 goto sgpt
::echo convert gpt >> %XBO_DP_SCRIPT%
:sgpt

:: Make destructive drive changes
::%XBO_DISKPART% /s %XBO_DP_SCRIPT%
:: End of diskpart remove existing partitions (works but clunky since partitions have to be removed individually)


:: Calculate partition sizes, creation moved to gdisk below
:: Partition 1: Temp Content
CALL :Calc %XBOX_TEMP_SIZE_IN_BYTES%/1024/1024
echo * Temp Content: MByte 
Size: '%XBO_CALC_RESULT%'                                  * >> %XBO_LOG% 2>&1
set /a XBOX_TEMP_SIZE_IN_MBYTES=%XBO_CALC_RESULT%
::echo create partition primary size=%XBOX_TEMP_SIZE_IN_MBYTES% offset=1024 >> %XBO_DP_SCRIPT%

:selsize
echo.
echo Select partition layout:
set XBO_SIZE=
echo (a) Autosize Non-Standard
echo (b) 500GB Standard
echo (c) 1TB Standard
echo (d) 2TB Standard
echo.
set /p XBO_SIZE=?
echo.
if not '%XBO_SIZE%'=='' set choice=%choice:~0,1%
if '%XBO_SIZE%'=='a' goto sizea
if '%XBO_SIZE%'=='b' goto sizeb
if '%XBO_SIZE%'=='c' goto sizec
if '%XBO_SIZE%'=='d' goto sized
echo "%XBO_SIZE%" is not valid please try again
echo.
goto selsize

:: Partition 2: User Content

:sizea
:: Treat all Non-Standard size drives as 500GB drives but add the spare space to 'User Content'
set DISK_GUID=%DISK_GUID_500GB%
set DISK_NAME=(Auto)
:: Size of the device in bytes
CALL :Calc %XBO_DISK_SECTORS%*%DEV_LOGICAL_BLOCK_SIZE_IN_BYTES%
:: New user content partition size (eg. Using a 500G drive it's rougly 392733679616 bytes = 365G )
CALL :Calc %XBO_CALC_RESULT%-%XBOX_TEMP_SIZE_IN_BYTES%-%XBOX_SUPPORT_SIZE_IN_BYTES%-%XBOX_UPDATE_SIZE_IN_BYTES%-%XBOX_UPDATE_SIZE2_IN_BYTES%
echo * User Content: Byte Size:  '%XBO_CALC_RESULT%'                           * >> %XBO_LOG% 2>&1
:: Align the data to the nearest gig
CALL :Calc %XBO_CALC_RESULT%/1024/1024/1024
echo * User Content: GByte Size: '%XBO_CALC_RESULT%'                                    * >> %XBO_LOG% 2>&1
CALL :Calc %XBO_CALC_RESULT%*1024
goto finsize

:sizeb
:: Could force all drives >500GB to be 500GB equivalent
set DISK_GUID=%DISK_GUID_500GB%
set DISK_NAME=(500GB)
:: Xbox One Standard 500GB User Partion
CALL :Calc 391915765760/1024/1024
:: CHANGEME: Xbox One Large 500GB User Partion
::CALL :Calc 392732606464/1024/1024
goto finsize

:sizec
:: Could force all drives >1TB to be 1TB equivalent
set DISK_GUID=%DISK_GUID_1TB%
set DISK_NAME=(1TB)
:: Xbox One Standard 1TB User Partion
CALL :Calc 838592364544/1024/1024
:: CHANGEME: Xbox One Large 1TB User Partion
::CALL :Calc 892828909568/1024/1024
goto finsize

:sized
:: Could force all drives >2TB to be 2TB equivalent
set DISK_GUID=%DISK_GUID_2TB%
set DISK_NAME=(2TB)
:: Xbox One Standard 2TB User Partion
CALL :Calc 1784558911488/1024/1024
:: CHANGEME: Xbox One Large 2TB User Partion
::CALL :Calc 1893023612928/1024/1024
goto finsize

:finsize
echo * User Content: MByte Size: '%XBO_CALC_RESULT%'                                 * >> %XBO_LOG% 2>&1
set /a XBOX_USER_SIZE_IN_MBYTES=%XBO_CALC_RESULT%
::echo create partition primary size=%XBOX_USER_SIZE_IN_MBYTES% >> %XBO_DP_SCRIPT%

:: Partition 3: System Support
CALL :Calc %XBOX_SUPPORT_SIZE_IN_BYTES%/1024/1024
echo * System Support: MByte Size: '%XBO_CALC_RESULT%'                                * >> %XBO_LOG% 2>&1
set /a XBOX_SUPPORT_SIZE_IN_MBYTES=%XBO_CALC_RESULT%
::echo create partition primary size=%XBOX_SUPPORT_SIZE_IN_MBYTES% >> %XBO_DP_SCRIPT%

:: Partition 4: System Update
CALL :Calc %XBOX_UPDATE_SIZE_IN_BYTES%/1024/1024
echo * System Update: MByte Size: '%XBO_CALC_RESULT%'                                 * >> %XBO_LOG% 2>&1
set /a XBOX_UPDATE_SIZE_IN_MBYTES=%XBO_CALC_RESULT%
::echo create partition primary size=%XBOX_UPDATE_SIZE_IN_MBYTES% >> %XBO_DP_SCRIPT%

:: Partition 5: System Update 2
CALL :Calc %XBOX_UPDATE_SIZE2_IN_BYTES%/1024/1024
echo * System Update 2: MByte Size: '%XBO_CALC_RESULT%'                                * >> %XBO_LOG% 2>&1
set /a XBOX_UPDATE_SIZE2_IN_MBYTES=%XBO_CALC_RESULT%
::echo create partition primary size=%XBOX_UPDATE_SIZE2_IN_MBYTES% >> %XBO_DP_SCRIPT%


:: Start of gdisk remove existing partitions (destroys all with one option)
:: Replaced with diskpart (remove existing partitions)
echo * Removing existing partitions with %XBO_GDISK% . . .                    *
echo o > %XBO_GD_SCRIPT%
echo y >> %XBO_GD_SCRIPT%
echo w >> %XBO_GD_SCRIPT%
echo y >> %XBO_GD_SCRIPT%
:: Make destructive GUID drive changes
echo. >> %XBO_LOG% 2>&1
%XBO_GDISK% \\.\physicaldrive%XBO_FORMAT_DRIVE% < %XBO_GD_SCRIPT% >> %XBO_LOG% 2>&1
:: End of gdisk remove existing partitions (destroys all with one option)


:: Create paritions and set GUID values
:: Windows doesn't like this much, works fine but Windows loses drive letters and things
echo * Creating new partitions with %XBO_GDISK% . . .                         *
echo x > %XBO_GD_SCRIPT%
echo g >> %XBO_GD_SCRIPT%
echo %DISK_GUID% >> %XBO_GD_SCRIPT%

echo m >> %XBO_GD_SCRIPT%
echo n >> %XBO_GD_SCRIPT%
echo 1 >> %XBO_GD_SCRIPT%
echo. >> %XBO_GD_SCRIPT%
echo +%XBOX_TEMP_SIZE_IN_MBYTES%M >> %XBO_GD_SCRIPT%
echo 700 >> %XBO_GD_SCRIPT%
echo x >> %XBO_GD_SCRIPT%
echo c >> %XBO_GD_SCRIPT%
:: Not needed when only one partition exists
::echo 1 >> %XBO_GD_SCRIPT%
echo %TEMP_CONTENT_GUID% >> %XBO_GD_SCRIPT%

echo m >> %XBO_GD_SCRIPT%
echo n >> %XBO_GD_SCRIPT%
echo 2 >> %XBO_GD_SCRIPT%
echo. >> %XBO_GD_SCRIPT%
echo +%XBOX_USER_SIZE_IN_MBYTES%M >> %XBO_GD_SCRIPT%
echo 700 >> %XBO_GD_SCRIPT%
echo x >> %XBO_GD_SCRIPT%
echo c >> %XBO_GD_SCRIPT%
echo 2 >> %XBO_GD_SCRIPT%
echo %USER_CONTENT_GUID% >> %XBO_GD_SCRIPT%

echo m >> %XBO_GD_SCRIPT%
echo n >> %XBO_GD_SCRIPT%
echo 3 >> %XBO_GD_SCRIPT%
echo. >> %XBO_GD_SCRIPT%
echo +%XBOX_SUPPORT_SIZE_IN_MBYTES%M >> %XBO_GD_SCRIPT%
echo 700 >> %XBO_GD_SCRIPT%
echo x >> %XBO_GD_SCRIPT%
echo c >> %XBO_GD_SCRIPT%
echo 3 >> %XBO_GD_SCRIPT%
echo %SYSTEM_SUPPORT_GUID% >> %XBO_GD_SCRIPT%

echo m >> %XBO_GD_SCRIPT%
echo n >> %XBO_GD_SCRIPT%
echo 4 >> %XBO_GD_SCRIPT%
echo. >> %XBO_GD_SCRIPT%
echo +%XBOX_UPDATE_SIZE_IN_MBYTES%M >> %XBO_GD_SCRIPT%
echo 700 >> %XBO_GD_SCRIPT%
echo x >> %XBO_GD_SCRIPT%
echo c >> %XBO_GD_SCRIPT%
echo 4 >> %XBO_GD_SCRIPT%
echo %SYSTEM_UPDATE_GUID% >> %XBO_GD_SCRIPT%

echo m >> %XBO_GD_SCRIPT%
echo n >> %XBO_GD_SCRIPT%
echo 5 >> %XBO_GD_SCRIPT%
echo. >> %XBO_GD_SCRIPT%
echo +%XBOX_UPDATE_SIZE2_IN_MBYTES%M >> %XBO_GD_SCRIPT%
echo 700 >> %XBO_GD_SCRIPT%
echo x >> %XBO_GD_SCRIPT%
echo c >> %XBO_GD_SCRIPT%
echo 5 >> %XBO_GD_SCRIPT%
echo %SYSTEM_UPDATE2_GUID% >> %XBO_GD_SCRIPT%

echo w >> %XBO_GD_SCRIPT%
echo y >> %XBO_GD_SCRIPT%

:: Make destructive GUID drive changes
%XBO_GDISK% \\.\physicaldrive%XBO_FORMAT_DRIVE% < %XBO_GD_SCRIPT% >> %XBO_LOG% 2>&1


:: CHANGEME: Comment out the line below with "::" if you want the option to
:: reset the disk after gdisk and before diskpart. Gdisk can take time to
:: apply requested changes thus the 30 second "time to settle" bit below.
goto nreset
echo.
echo.
echo If the drive is connected by USB you may want to choose "Y" here
echo This is equivalent to physically disconnecting and reconnecting the cable
choice.exe /M "Reset USB mass storage devices "
if ERRORLEVEL 2 goto nreset
echo. >> %XBO_LOG% 2>&1
%XBO_DEVCON% restart USB\ROOT_HUB20 >> %XBO_LOG% 2>&1
:nreset

echo.
echo.
:: gdisk creates partitions very quickly, perhaps too quickly?
:: diskpart will not see the newly created volumes correctly without pausing
start /wait choice.exe /N /C C /T %XBO_TIMEOUT% /D C /M "Giving USB/SATA devices time to settle, please wait . . ."

:: Check volume status
echo list volume > %XBO_DP_SCRIPT%
%XBO_DISKPART% /s %XBO_DP_SCRIPT%
echo.
%XBO_DISKPART% /s %XBO_DP_SCRIPT% >> %XBO_LOG% 2>&1
echo. >> %XBO_LOG% 2>&1


:: Use format instead of diskpart to add a volume label
:: format doesn't support spaces in volume labels, fix with diskpart in next step
echo * Formatting new partitions with %XBO_FORMAT% . . .    *
%XBO_FORMAT% \\?\Volume{%TEMP_CONTENT_GUID%} /FS:NTFS /V:Temp_Content /Q /Y >> %XBO_LOG% 2>&1
%XBO_FORMAT% \\?\Volume{%USER_CONTENT_GUID%} /FS:NTFS /V:User_Content /Q /Y >> %XBO_LOG% 2>&1
%XBO_FORMAT% \\?\Volume{%SYSTEM_SUPPORT_GUID%} /FS:NTFS /V:System_Support /Q /Y >> %XBO_LOG% 2>&1
%XBO_FORMAT% \\?\Volume{%SYSTEM_UPDATE_GUID%} /FS:NTFS /V:System_Update /Q /Y >> %XBO_LOG% 2>&1
%XBO_FORMAT% \\?\Volume{%SYSTEM_UPDATE2_GUID%} /FS:NTFS /V:System_Update_2 /Q /Y >> %XBO_LOG% 2>&1


:: Finally use diskpart to format and assign drive letters so that we can copy files
echo * Formatting and assigning drive letters with %XBO_DISKPART% . . .
:: Rescan for newly added devices
echo rescan > %XBO_DP_SCRIPT%
echo list volume > %XBO_DP_SCRIPT%
for /f "tokens=2" %%A in ('%XBO_DISKPART% /s %XBO_DP_SCRIPT% ^| findstr /b /r /c:".*Temp_Conten"') do (
echo select volume %%A > !XBO_DP_SCRIPT!
echo format FS=NTFS LABEL="Temp Content" QUICK NOERR >> !XBO_DP_SCRIPT!
echo assign letter=!TEMP_CONTENT_LETTER! NOERR >> !XBO_DP_SCRIPT!
!XBO_DISKPART! /s !XBO_DP_SCRIPT! >> !XBO_LOG! 2>&1
)


echo list volume > %XBO_DP_SCRIPT%
for /f "tokens=2" %%A in ('%XBO_DISKPART% /s %XBO_DP_SCRIPT% ^| findstr /b /r /c:".*User_Conten"') do (
echo select volume %%A > !XBO_DP_SCRIPT!
echo format FS=NTFS LABEL="User Content" QUICK NOERR >> !XBO_DP_SCRIPT!
echo assign letter=!USER_CONTENT_LETTER! NOERR >> !XBO_DP_SCRIPT!
!XBO_DISKPART! /s !XBO_DP_SCRIPT! >> !XBO_LOG! 2>&1
)

echo list volume > %XBO_DP_SCRIPT%
for /f "tokens=2" %%A in ('%XBO_DISKPART% /s %XBO_DP_SCRIPT% ^| findstr /b /r /c:".*System_Supp"') do (
echo select volume %%A > !XBO_DP_SCRIPT!
echo format FS=NTFS LABEL="System Support" QUICK NOERR >> !XBO_DP_SCRIPT!
echo assign letter=!SYSTEM_SUPPORT_LETTER! NOERR >> !XBO_DP_SCRIPT!
!XBO_DISKPART! /s !XBO_DP_SCRIPT! >> !XBO_LOG! 2>&1
)

echo list volume > %XBO_DP_SCRIPT%
for /f "tokens=2" %%A in ('%XBO_DISKPART% /s %XBO_DP_SCRIPT% ^| findstr /b /r /c:".*System_Upda.*12"') do (
echo select volume %%A > !XBO_DP_SCRIPT!
echo format FS=NTFS LABEL="System Update" QUICK NOERR >> !XBO_DP_SCRIPT!
echo assign letter=!SYSTEM_UPDATE_LETTER! NOERR >> !XBO_DP_SCRIPT!
!XBO_DISKPART! /s !XBO_DP_SCRIPT! >> !XBO_LOG! 2>&1
)

echo list volume > %XBO_DP_SCRIPT%
for /f "tokens=2" %%A in ('%XBO_DISKPART% /s %XBO_DP_SCRIPT% ^| findstr /b /r /c:".*System_Upda.*7168"') do (
echo select volume %%A > !XBO_DP_SCRIPT!
echo format FS=NTFS LABEL="System Update 2" QUICK NOERR >> !XBO_DP_SCRIPT!
echo assign letter=!SYSTEM_UPDATE2_LETTER! NOERR >> !XBO_DP_SCRIPT!
!XBO_DISKPART! /s !XBO_DP_SCRIPT! >> !XBO_LOG! 2>&1
)

:: Check volume status
echo list volume > %XBO_DP_SCRIPT%
%XBO_DISKPART% /s %XBO_DP_SCRIPT%
echo.
%XBO_DISKPART% /s %XBO_DP_SCRIPT% >> %XBO_LOG% 2>&1
echo. >> %XBO_LOG% 2>&1

if exist %SYSTEM_UPDATE_LETTER%\ goto dexists
goto ndrive

:ndrive
set XBO_MESSAGE=* No USB/SATA drives found                                           *
goto endbat

:edrive
set XBO_MESSAGE=* Xbox One Drive Selection Cancelled                                 *
goto endbat

:dexists
set XBO_MESSAGE=* Found the %SYSTEM_UPDATE_LETTER% drive.                                                *
echo.

CALL :ListPart
goto endbat



:: FUNCTIONS

:Calc
:: Round down all sizes
for /f "tokens=1" %%A in ('%XBO_CALC% Floor^(%1^)') do (
set XBO_CALC_RESULT=%%A
)
GOTO:EOF


:GetSect
echo p > %XBO_GD_SCRIPT%
for /f "tokens=7" %%A in ('%XBO_GDISK% \\.\physicaldrive%XBO_FORMAT_DRIVE% ^< %XBO_GD_SCRIPT% ^| findstr /b /r /c:".*Disk \\\\.\\physicaldrive.:"') do (
set XBO_DISK_SECTORS=%%A
)
GOTO:EOF


:GetBlock
echo p > %XBO_GD_SCRIPT%
for /f "tokens=4" %%A in ('%XBO_GDISK% \\.\physicaldrive%XBO_FORMAT_DRIVE% ^< %XBO_GD_SCRIPT% ^| findstr /b /r /c:".*Logical sector size:"') do (
set DEV_LOGICAL_BLOCK_SIZE_IN_BYTES=%%A
)
GOTO:EOF


:ListPart
:: start of list_part_info.sh equivalent
echo select disk %XBO_FORMAT_DRIVE% > %XBO_DP_SCRIPT%
echo detail disk >> %XBO_DP_SCRIPT%
:: Get Disk GUID
for /f "tokens=2* delims={}" %%A in ('%XBO_DISKPART% /s %XBO_DP_SCRIPT% ^| findstr /b /r /c:"Disk ID"') do (
set XBO_DISK_GUID=%%A
)

echo.
echo GUID                                 Dev Size    Name
echo %XBO_DISK_GUID%             %DISK_NAME%

echo. >> %XBO_LOG% 2>&1
echo GUID                                 Dev Size    Name >> %XBO_LOG% 2>&1
echo %XBO_DISK_GUID%             %DISK_NAME% >> %XBO_LOG% 2>&1

set /a XBO_PART_CNT=0
:: Get Volume GUID(s)- 1st get drive letters
for /f "tokens=3,4,5,8,9" %%A in ('%XBO_DISKPART% /s %XBO_DP_SCRIPT% ^| findstr /b /r /c:" *Volume [^#0]"') do (
set /a XBO_PART_CNT+=1
set XBO_PART!XBO_PART_CNT!_LETTER=%%A:
set XBO_PART!XBO_PART_CNT!_SIZE=%%D %%E
CALL :StrLen LEN XBO_PART!XBO_PART_CNT!_SIZE
CALL :Calc 7-!LEN!
CALL :GetSpaces SPC XBO_CALC_RESULT
set XBO_PART!XBO_PART_CNT!_SIZEP=!SPC!%%D %%E
:: 2nd get GUID(s)
for /f "tokens=2 delims={}" %%G in ('%XBO_MOUNTVOL% %%A:\ /L ^| findstr /b /r /c:" *\\\\?\\Volume"') do (
    set XBO_PART!XBO_PART_CNT!_GUID=%%G
    CALL :UpCase XBO_PART!XBO_PART_CNT!_GUID
)
:: 3rd get volume labels
for /f "tokens=6*" %%V in ('vol %%A: ^| findstr /b /r /c:" *Volume in drive"') do (
    set XBO_PART!XBO_PART_CNT!_NAME=%%V %%W
)
CALL :PrtPart XBO_PART!XBO_PART_CNT!_GUID XBO_PART!XBO_PART_CNT!_LETTER XBO_PART!XBO_PART_CNT!_SIZEP XBO_PART!XBO_PART_CNT!_NAME
)
echo.
echo. >> %XBO_LOG% 2>&1
GOTO:EOF
:: end of list_part_info.sh equivalent


:PrtPart
echo !%1! !%2!  !%3! '!%4!'
echo !%1! !%2!  !%3! '!%4!' >> %XBO_LOG% 2>&1
GOTO:EOF


:UpCase
:: Subroutine to convert a variable VALUE to all UPPER CASE.
:: The argument for this subroutine is the variable NAME.
FOR %%i IN ("a=A" "b=B" "c=C" "d=D" "e=E" "f=F" "g=G" "h=H" "i=I" "j=J" "k=K" "l=L" "m=M" "n=N" "o=O" "p=P" "q=Q" "r=R" "s=S" "t=T" "u=U" "v=V" "w=W" "x=X" "y=Y" "z=Z") DO CALL SET "%1=%%%1:%%~i%%"
GOTO:EOF


:StrLen <resultVar> <stringVar>
(
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set "s=!%~2!#"
set "len=0"
for %%P in (4096 2048 1024 512 256 128 64 32 16 8 4 2 1) do (
    if "!s:~%%P,1!" NEQ "" (
        set /a "len+=%%P"
        set "s=!s:~%%P!"
    )
)
)
(
endlocal
set "%~1=%len%"
GOTO:EOF
)


:GetSpaces <resultVar> <numericVar>
(
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set "s=!%~2!"
set "spc="
for /l %%I IN (1,1,!s!) do (
    set "spc=!spc! "
)
)
(
endlocal
set "%~1=%spc%"
GOTO:EOF
)


:endbat
echo.
echo %XBO_MESSAGE%

echo. >> %XBO_LOG% 2>&1
echo %XBO_MESSAGE% >> %XBO_LOG% 2>&1
echo. >> %XBO_LOG% 2>&1
date /T >> %XBO_LOG% 2>&1
time /T >> %XBO_LOG% 2>&1

echo.
echo * Script execution complete.                                         *
echo.
echo * This script will now change the command line interface back to the *
echo * default language.                                                  *
echo.
pause


:: Attempt to restore everything back to original language
cd %~dp0\Englishize_Cmd
call restore_xfix.bat
cd ..

ENDLOCAL
```

Please help. Thanks in advance. Mr. Rogers 
[Screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l8Qo8.png)

Comment: [Edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/46532589/edit) to add your code. An off site image of only part of the script inside an editor is no use to us at all. Your error will be related to a  `Set /A` statement somewhere!

Comment: You've only got one `Set /A` statement showing and on that one the `/A` isn't even needed. My guess is that the `:Calc` section of your code is where the issue may be of have been. You may need to post more of your code!

Comment: Thank You Compo, I have posted the entire Code as question body. Mr.R

Comment: First of all, the script you've posted doesn't include the first 183 lines! I don't think that it really matters though because, _and I know this isn't what you want to hear,_ I really think you should contact [XfiX](https://twitter.com/mpdavig) for support with their scripts, I know you've already tried via their YouTube channel, but it's only been a couple of days and patience is a virtue.

Comment: Okay thanks so much!

Comment: The parsed command of `for /f …` loop results to e.g. `calc Floor(391915765760/1024/1024)`  in the `:Calc` subroutine. Run this command in an open `cmd` prompt (after navigating to the batch working directory). What happens then?  Run `where calc` as well there. What is the result?

Comment: @MarcusRogers Don't use `%variable%` or `!variable!` in an __arithmetic expression__. Use instead just `variable`. Run in a command prompt window `set /?` and read the help output with several pages explaining in detail why in an arithmetic expression it is recommended to just write the variable name instead of referencing the value of the environment variable immediately or delayed.

Comment: @Compo You were right! It has to be in the Calc section somewhere! I just can not see where! it has to be when I select b for the 500 gb size! assistance would be brilliant!